# Which one is more effective when building builders?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, default-value, builder

NOTE: All builders are for unit-testing only.

So I have been creating builders and as I have been creating them I have started noticing that some of the other builders, already in place, follow a bit of a different pattern.

Thought I ask here which one is more effective.

My way of doing it is this:

```
public class Builder
{
    public Builders()
    {
        SetDefaults();
    }

    private void SetDefaults()
    {
       // Setting my defaults
    }
}
```

The other way that is in place:

```
public class Builder
{     
    public Builder WithDefaults()
    {
       // Setting my defaults
    }
}
```

In my opinion the first one is more effective because you just create your builder and it does the default setting for you automatically.

In the other case you have to explicitly call the WithDefaults method to set all of the defaults before you go on building it.

The second one seems more error prone since some objects that need to be build can throw null exceptions if they don't have all of their fields set up.

Maybe I am missing something subtle here so I decided to ask you about which one is more effective moving forward.

Thank you.

Comment: If you have to call "WithDefaults" they're not really defaults, are they?

Comment: @JonSkeet that's a great point, thank you!

Comment: Well if i really wanted to find a pro for the second method it would be this one : WithDefault could still be used to reset the builder attributes to their defaults....

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest a third option. Since the builder is supposed to reduce the amount of test code by removing the object(s) initialization in a clear and meaningful way - why declare that you're using the defaults?
In it's own is tells nothing about what the actual defaults are and you have the risk of test writer forgetting to call "WithDefaults".

Take a look at [this post for example on how it's done](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/07/15/flexible-and-expressive-unit-tests-with-the-builder-pattern/)

Instead use the constructor to set the defaults (of fields storing them) and only change them if explicitly asked to.
That way you get an initialized object with minimum and meaningful builder calls.